# Apache Cassandra Storage-Conf.xml

Tags: xml, cassandra

I downloaded and extracted Apache Cassandra 2.0.1. However I cant find storage-conf.xml inside ../conf folder. I only have the following files.

```
root@Itanium:/etc/apache-cassandra-2.0.1/conf# ls
cassandra-env.sh                cqlshrc.sample
cassandra-rackdc.properties     log4j-server.properties
cassandra-topology.properties   log4j-tools.properties
cassandra-topology.yaml         README.txt
cassandra.yaml                  triggers
commitlog_archiving.properties
root@Itanium:/etc/apache-cassandra-2.0.1/conf#
```

I would really appreciate if anyone sheds light on this. Am I downloading the wrong version? Is storage-conf.xml deprecated?

Appreciate all your responses.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/StorageConfiguration

> Prior to the 0.7 release, Cassandra storage configuration is described by the conf/storage-conf.xml file. As of 0.7, it is described by the conf/cassandra.yaml file.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Appreciate you giving me the link.